# how to get values from datepickerdialog

Tags: android, datepicker

how to get the value we pressed on date picker dialog

```
public void showDateTimePicker4(){
    final Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    date = Calendar.getInstance();

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            year = datePicker.getYear();
            month = datePicker.getMonth();
            day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            date.set(year, month, day);
        }
    };
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, date.get(Calendar.YEAR), date.get(Calendar.MONTH), date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() -1000);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

and this is my syntax

```
jadwal4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showDateTimePicker4();
            currentDateString4 = date.getTime().toString();
            jadwalpilih4.setText(currentDateString4);



        }
    });
```

I can't get custom value, I only get the current time value

Comment: Showing a dialog does not pause execution of your code. It immediately continues to the `currentDateString4 = ...` line, which is why you don't get the right value. Move the two lines after `showDateTimePicker4();` to the end of the `onDateSet()` method.

Comment: set text inside `public void onDateSet`. You can't know the date selected before it is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tty this way

```
String selectedDate = ""; // decleare it in global scope
public void showDateTimePicker4(){
    final Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    date = Calendar.getInstance();

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
               .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
               .append(" ");

            // set selected date into textview
            jadwalpilih4.setText(selectedDate);
        }
    };
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, date.get(Calendar.YEAR), date.get(Calendar.MONTH), date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() -1000);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
  public void selectDate(View view) {
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_ENGLISH, Locale.US);
              String mDate = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
               jadwalpilih4.setText(mDate);


            }
        }, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        mDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: In my case DATE_FORMAT_ENGLISH is yyyy-mm-dd, you can use as per your requirment

Comment: Because you are using wrong format for convert the date

Comment: Please check https://www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format and set format as per your requirement.